# Quantum Mechanics Postulates

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Usually when people present the postulates of quantum mechanics they give a very small list of postulates. However, when they try to solve different cases they often need more axioms than what they presented.
**Can someone write a detailed list of all quantum mechanics postulates?**

Comment: Can you give an example of an additional postulate you have seen someone invoke beyond the [usual postulates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html)?

Comment: One example is the fact that you actually need classical physics in order to determine the potential V in Schrodinger equation (and this comes with many postulates of classical mechanics)

Comment: I wouldn't call the choice of potential a *postulate.* The postulate is that the state evolves according to the Schrodinger equation. From a purely mathematical point of view, one can consider the Schrodinger equation with any Hamiltonian operator obeying the postulates. The role of the postulates is simply to define the space of possibilities.  Typical reasons to choose a specific Hamiltonian include (a) it describes a real physical system we are interested in, or (b) it is a solvable toy problem that gives us some generally applicable insight.